# How to set up a generic factor with R

Tags: r

I work a lot with data that uses the codification for municipalities provided by the National Statistics Institute of my country. Since this classification is usually represented as a non-ordered categorical data, I usually convert the data from int to factor using `var <- as.factor(var)` and it always works fine for me.

However, I have a concern about the levels of these factors: I often work with datasets which doesn't present all of these codes (5570 in total, by the way), and isn't rare that I do joins between these datasets, leading to this message: `Warning message: Column CO_MUN joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`.

There is a way to manipulate the `as.factor()` call to keep the factor levels from the original base?

Thanks!

Comment: Any time you're dealing with `factor`s and which to combine datasets, you need to either (a) convert to non-`factor`, combine, then re-`factor`; or (b) update each datasets' `levels` before combining them. I'm generally a fan of the first method, but it's a preference (and code proficiency) thing.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I didn't had any problem related to this question but I can imagine how this operation may fail because of this. I wonder if there is a reference of good practices of working with factors, do you know any?

Comment: Honestly, I avoid them until I desperately need them (e.g., `ggplot2`). There are certainly regression types that really "need" factors over ordinal types, but they're not really in my daily needs. That's my take, though, and I know others are more comfortable with them. Have you looked at the `forcats` package? I don't use it, but I believe it has a lot of "helper" functions for dealing with factors.

Comment: For me, the `forcats` library is useful to work with your second scenario, assuming the opposite of your preference. I tought that maybe there is some package that "translates" a generic factor to other, just like a join would do, copying the levels and joining by the labels, but I really don't know which way is the best, so I prefer working as you do: avoiding the factors as much as I can.